# How to Drawable Rotating around its Top Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am getting strange results with the following code:

```
  Animation a = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
                Animation.ZORDER_TOP, 0.5f, Animation.ZORDER_TOP,
                0.5f);
        a.setRepeatCount(-1);
        a.setDuration(1000);
        img.startAnimation(a);
```

Whats the right way to specify the axis point (top of the drawable)?

Comment: You are incorrectly passing `Animation.ZORDER_TOP` parameter. Those parameters should be one of `Animation.ABSOLUTE`, `Animation.RELATIVE_ TO_SELF` or `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT`. What do you mean by saying *top of the drawable*? What happens currently?

Comment: i want change Angle of rotation?

Comment: Angle is specified by first two parameters: from `0` degree to `360` degree. Change them by your needs.

Comment: i did,but it dosent changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will work "rotationY" means it will rotate Y Direction, "rotationX" means it will rotate X Direction

```
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);
    animation.setDuration(600);
    animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
```